# Having Trouble with multiple "groupby" with a variable and a category (binned data)

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

```
df.dtypes

Close       float64
eqId          int64
date         object
IntDate       int64
expiry        int64
delta         int64
ivMid       float64
conf        float64
Skew        float64
psc         float64
vol_B      category
dtype: object

gb = df.groupby([df['vol_B'],df['expiry']])

gb.describe()
```

I get a long error message with the final line being

```
AttributeError: 'Categorical' object has no attribute 'flags'
```

When I perform a `groupby` on each of them separately they each (independently) work great, I just can not perform multiple `groupby` with one of the variables being a "bin."

Also, when I use 2 other variables I am able to perform multiple `groupby` &ndash I successfully performed this:

```
gb = df.groupby([df['delta'],df['expiry']])
```

Comment: [Bug fixed in pandas 0.17](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10495) – see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32000652/2662901).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was facing a similar issue as the OP and found this question while looking for solutions. A simple hack that worked for me after going through the pandas [documentation for categorical variables](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) was to change the type of the categorical variable before grouping.

Since vol_B is the categorical variable in your case, you should try the following

```
#Depending on the content of vol_B you can do astype(int) or astype(float) as well.
gb = df.groupby([df['vol_B'].astype(str), df['expiry']])
```

I haven't gone into the details of why this works and that doesn't but if I get into it, I will update the answer.

Comment: I can't figure out how this is not a bug. Why 'str' would work while 'category' not? I can't figure out how this is not a bug

Comment: Not sure if exactly the same, but might be in the process of being fixed here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10460