# Pandas groupby and describe flags AttributeError

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror, describe

I have a bunch of data stored in `vals`. The indices are monotonic, but not continuous. I'm attempting to do some analysis on histograms of the data, so I've created the following structure:

```
hist = pd.DataFrame(vals)

hist['bins'] = pd.cut(vals, 100)
```

This is data taken from an experimental instrument and I know that some of the `bins` have only 1 or 2 counts in them, which I'm trying to remove. I've tried using `groupby` as follows and get the following error (Full traceback included at the end of the note):

```
hist.groupby('bins').describe()

AttributeError: 'Categorical' object has no attribute 'flags'
```

However, when I do the following, the error does not show up and I get the expected result:

```
In[]:  hist.index = hist.bins
In[]:  hist['bins'] = hist.index
In[]:  desc = hist.groupby('bins').describe()
In[]:  desc.index.names = ['bins', 'describe']

Out[]: **describe with MultiIndex for rows.**
```

If I don't include the second line `hist['bins'] = hist.index`, I still get an `AttributeError: 'Categorical' object has no attribute 'flags'` and to the best that I can tell, the traceback is identical.

Can someone explain what the `flags` are and why they only seem to work when I set the `index` to `bins` and then replace the `bins` by the version stored in the `index`?

My end goal is to remove the data for bins with counts <= 6. If someone has an easier workaround than the way I'm going after it, I'd also be grateful.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f606a051f2e4> in <module>()
----> 1 hist.groupby('bins').describe()

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\displayhook.pyc in __call__(self, result)
    245             self.start_displayhook()
    246             self.write_output_prompt()
--> 247             format_dict, md_dict = self.compute_format_data(result)
    248             self.write_format_data(format_dict, md_dict)
    249             self.update_user_ns(result)

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\displayhook.pyc in compute_format_data(self, result)
    155 
    156         """
--> 157         return self.shell.display_formatter.format(result)
    158 
    159     def write_format_data(self, format_dict, md_dict=None):

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.pyc in format(self, obj, include, exclude)
    150             md = None
    151             try:
--> 152                 data = formatter(obj)
    153             except:
    154                 # FIXME: log the exception

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.pyc in __call__(self, obj)
    479                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    480                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 481             printer.pretty(obj)
    482             printer.flush()
    483             return stream.getvalue()

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.pyc in pretty(self, obj)
    360                             if callable(meth):
    361                                 return meth(obj, self, cycle)
--> 362             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    363         finally:
    364             self.end_group()

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.pyc in _default_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    480     if getattr(klass, '__repr__', None) not in _baseclass_reprs:
    481         # A user-provided repr.
--> 482         p.text(repr(obj))
    483         return
    484     p.begin_group(1, '<')

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.pyc in __repr__(self)
     62         Yields Bytestring in Py2, Unicode String in py3.
     63         """
---> 64         return str(self)
     65 
     66 

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.pyc in __str__(self)
     42         if compat.PY3:
     43             return self.__unicode__()
---> 44         return self.__bytes__()
     45 
     46     def __bytes__(self):

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.pyc in __bytes__(self)
     54 
     55         encoding = get_option("display.encoding")
---> 56         return self.__unicode__().encode(encoding, 'replace')
     57 
     58     def __repr__(self):

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in __unicode__(self)
    507             width = None
    508         self.to_string(buf=buf, max_rows=max_rows, max_cols=max_cols,
--> 509                        line_width=width, show_dimensions=show_dimensions)
    510 
    511         return buf.getvalue()

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in to_string(self, buf, columns, col_space, colSpace, header, index, na_rep, formatters, float_format, sparsify, index_names, justify, line_width, max_rows, max_cols, show_dimensions)
   1340                                            max_rows=max_rows,
   1341                                            max_cols=max_cols,
-> 1342                                            show_dimensions=show_dimensions)
   1343         formatter.to_string()
   1344 

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.pyc in __init__(self, frame, buf, columns, col_space, header, index, na_rep, formatters, justify, float_format, sparsify, index_names, line_width, max_rows, max_cols, show_dimensions, **kwds)
    345             self.columns = frame.columns
    346 
--> 347         self._chk_truncate()
    348 
    349     def _chk_truncate(self):

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.pyc in _chk_truncate(self)
    410             else:
    411                 row_num = max_rows_adj // 2
--> 412                 frame = concat((frame.iloc[:row_num, :], frame.iloc[-row_num:, :]))
    413             self.tr_row_num = row_num
    414 

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.pyc in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, copy)
    752                        keys=keys, levels=levels, names=names,
    753                        verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
--> 754                        copy=copy)
    755     return op.get_result()
    756 

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.pyc in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, join_axes, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy)
    884         self.copy = copy
    885 
--> 886         self.new_axes = self._get_new_axes()
    887 
    888     def get_result(self):

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.pyc in _get_new_axes(self)
    957                 new_axes[i] = ax
    958 
--> 959         new_axes[self.axis] = self._get_concat_axis()
    960         return new_axes
    961 

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.pyc in _get_concat_axis(self)
   1009 
   1010         if self.keys is None:
-> 1011             concat_axis = _concat_indexes(indexes)
   1012         else:
   1013             concat_axis = _make_concat_multiindex(indexes, self.keys,

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.pyc in _concat_indexes(indexes)
   1027 
   1028 def _concat_indexes(indexes):
-> 1029     return indexes[0].append(indexes[1:])
   1030 
   1031 

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.pyc in append(self, other)
   4603             arrays = []
   4604             for i in range(self.nlevels):
-> 4605                 label = self.get_level_values(i)
   4606                 appended = [o.get_level_values(i) for o in other]
   4607                 arrays.append(label.append(appended))

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.pyc in get_level_values(self, level)
   4239         unique = self.levels[num]  # .values
   4240         labels = self.labels[num]
-> 4241         filled = com.take_1d(unique.values, labels, fill_value=unique._na_value)
   4242         values = unique._simple_new(filled, self.names[num],
   4243                                     freq=getattr(unique, 'freq', None),

C:\Users\balterma\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.pyc in take_nd(arr, indexer, axis, out, fill_value, mask_info, allow_fill)
    829         out_shape[axis] = len(indexer)
    830         out_shape = tuple(out_shape)
--> 831         if arr.flags.f_contiguous and axis == arr.ndim - 1:
    832             # minor tweak that can make an order-of-magnitude difference
    833             # for dataframes initialized directly from 2-d ndarrays

AttributeError: 'Categorical' object has no attribute 'flags'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks to be be a bug with `Categorical` data that will be corrected in version 0.17.0 (issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10324)).

In the meantime, you could just cast the category to an `object` dtype - this is what was happening when you assigned to the index and back.

```
df['bins'] = df['bins'].astype(str)
```

Comment: Until 0.17.0 is released, you can install the pandas master branch from github `pip install git+https://github.com/pydata/pandas.git`. Categorical values do not raise this error anymore.